# wso2 identity server access-control-allow-origin

Tags: cors, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

We are running Wso2 Identity Server that has been modified to include CAS support by Ellucian.

I would like to be able to make CAS authentication calls to the Wso2 server using Javascript.  I need to find a way to add access-control-allow-origin headers.

I have found articles like this one:  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Invoking+an+Endpoint+from+a+Different+Domain .  But that won't work for me, because I don't have access to add dependencies to pom.xml as described in the bottom, to include the cors-filter.

Is there a way to add cors headers globally, across all authentication methods?  (CAS, OpenID, Saml, etc.)?   Or more specifically, just to the CAS calls?

If not, I'll likely try to include them using a proxy or on our load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the CORS filter jar from `repository/deployment/server/webapps/oauth2/WEB-INF/lib` to CAS endpoint lib folder and engage the filter as mentioned in the doc and it should work.

Or else you can write your own filter (or a value) and engage that as well.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon444/Valves